# Why am I getting "no longer accepting questions from this account"?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, asking-questions, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

*This question was initially posted on stackoverflow.com since meta.stackoverflow.com is "no longer accepting questions from this account."*

I got suspended (or in SO lingo, "boxed") recently, but I honestly do not know what I did wrong on this site as no reason was cited for it.

Here is Toronto's comment regarding my suspension: **After a
quick peek at these [my questions] I have to assume that he was
boxed for not appealing to whiners' whinings. That's not a good
reason.**

Is this *the* reason? If not, what is it?

More importantly, why do diamond moderators NOT disclose the reasons for suspension for each user?

Finally, why is meta.stackoverflow.com "no longer accepting questions from this account"?

Comment: You should have e-mailed the SO team, instead of posting off-topic. Oh wait, posting on SO and waiting for a move was actually a cool idea.

Comment: It's a bit of a strange place over there. Probably its better if you accept the suspension as a blessing in that you now don't need to visit that site.

Comment: Oh hey, this ended up on meta after all.

Comment: Diamond moderators, please be responsible for your actions and post answers to my questions.

Comment: Wow, check out your question history.  Reminds me of...Oh, wait. I'm not supposed to talk about *him* anymore.

Comment: @Robert Would you mind sharing *his* username?

Comment: @OTZ create a new account already. And be reasonable. The mods generally do a good job.

Comment: @OTZ: [See here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135854/evan-carroll)

Comment: Note: an example of why [Block migration if user is suspended/question-blocked at destination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination) should be implemented.

Comment: See also [Should the automated ban on questions used on SO apply to Meta as well?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67023/should-the-automated-ban-on-questions-used-on-so-apply-to-meta-as-well)

Answer (score 14):

It doesn't look like [your account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151121/otz) has been suspended, in the usual way.

The phrase, "no longer accepting questions from this account" indicates an [automated ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294) based on the number of downvotes your questions have received.  The system is programmed to refuse questions from accounts whose past questions have received a lot of downvotes.

And [yours have.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151121/otz)

Comment: @Robert I just got back from a 1-week suspension. The ban on question posting is what I discovered after that, which I think is what you are referring to.

Comment: @OTZ: The last person who had a question history like yours is serving out a *one year ban,* after much wailing and gnashing of teeth. Trust me, you don't want to go down that road; therein lies madness. Be thankful that we caught it early, while there's still time for reform.

Comment: @OTZ - do you understand the reasons for your suspension?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - if Meta is "no longer accepting questions from thie account" there is no chance of reform.

Comment: @APC: Ah, there is always hope.  The technical details are a closely-guarded secret, but I suspect the ban ages away after a certain undisclosed time.  Also, the Team can always be emailed with an apology.

Comment: @APC "For being too honest" is what seems to be the best explanation aside from Toronto's analysis.

Comment: @OTZ: The Team is supposed to give you a reason for being boxed.  You probably didn't get an email from them because you don't have an email address on file in your account information.  Why don't you just email them at Team@StackOverflow.com, and ask them why you were boxed for a week?

Comment: @Robert Or they could just answer directly on this page, which is much better since others can view it.

Comment: @APC In addition, I sense that some diamond mods are being somewhat inimical toward me; that kind of personal touch could have possibly involved, however unprofessional that may sound.

Comment: Or maybe, just maybe @OTZ, it's because you've been a jerk and asked many lousy questions and even gone so far as to *brag* about them, and then when they get downvoted/closed/deleted by the *community*, you blame the *moderators*.  Yeah, folks, good luck getting this guy to "reform."

Answer (score 10):

Because you were stubborn and not willing to accept our explanation for a lot of stuff. It's not right to ban people off of bad questions, but, you didn't accept (or at least understand the opposing side) the reasons why they were "bad".

And you probably wont accept this either as explanation.