# Clarify "no longer accepting questions from this account" error

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, bug, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Better explanation when account is blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62373/better-explanation-when-account-is-blocked)

A few months ago SO [started blocking questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294) from users with a history of poor questions; users get the error message:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

It's not clear to users who see this what they did wrong, or how to fix it, so they end up posting the error message on meta ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66973/why-am-i-getting-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68616/so-is-not-accepting-questions-from-my-account-anymore), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63432/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account), [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72173/understanding-how-preprocessor-works-in-this-program)). Is it possible to include an explanation in the error message, or make it link to a meta post or FAQ section that does? It's particularly important to tell them what they can do to fix the problem -- I'm not even sure what the answer to that is (post answers that get upvoted? e-mail team@?)

Comment: I agreed with Arjan's vote to close, though I will point out that this is the unusual case where the "dupe" has more votes than the original (and an Official Jeff Answer, though no red tag).

Comment: @Popular Jeff has an answer there too, and it's somewhat better, so closing is probably good

Comment: Yeah, that's part of what led to me choosing parentheses instead of bold and <blink>.

Comment: The very first thing they see is "users who can't be bothered to form sentences." I respectfully submit that such wording is not best from a public relations standpoint.

Comment: Also you need to give them an exact reason: Was it their IP address? Was it their score ratio of this vs. that? Etc, Just dumping it in their laps and telling them to figure out the problem won't help things.

Comment: On one hand Stackoverflow requires users to make perfectly crafted questions, but at the same time cannot even manage to make a _polite_ explanation if the user, or perhaps someone from the same ISP, does not.

Comment: @DanJidanniJacobson I'm not sure what you imagine commenting here is going to do; this was two years ago, nobody in charge is going to be looking at it

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelMrozek. I am probably lucky, for if they did see it I would probably get doubly banned. But that's the breaks.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: I'm not sure what you imagine commenting here is going to do. Questions and Answers (and to a lessor extent, Comments) persist ... and can be useful at *any* time ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> It's particularly important to tell them what they can do to fix the problem

We don't view this as a fixable problem in these cases.

Comment: So is the account permanently unable to post questions?

Comment: @michael they can technically still post answers but in my experience the types of users who tend to hit this filter are .. unlikely .. to produce an upvotable answer. They are free to try but it's not a situation where I think it would be helpful to encourage them to start "answering" things.

Comment: Is this something that goes away with time?  Or does it flag the account permanently and there's no way to undo it?

Comment: @erick it is permanent by IP, it is lower level than account

Comment: @JeffAtwood Like it's a hard thing to get a new IP... And people who are behind NATs be damned.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I get a new IP each time I reboot the router... how soon before I get a banned IP?

Comment: @JeffAtwood so getting a New IP will end the Ban?

Comment: Yikes! I share the same IP with thousands of others on my ISP.

Comment: Hypothetically, if I were to be on a shared IP and got banned due to some other user's faults, how can I file a request to become unbanned?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek No! the account doesn't not permanently get unable to post questions. I have touched this ban on physics.SE and get rid of it by posting some answers and raising flags.

Comment: @anupam "the account doesn't not permanently get unable to post questions." triple negative, nice!

Comment: It's time to use IPv6

Comment: @JeffAtwood Ahem Tor?

Comment: @JeffAtwood Ahem, Dynamic IPs?

Comment: Haha, if a banned user account is committed enough to go so far as to user tor to create a new account, they're pretty damned committed to staying around, aren't they?

Comment: I don't think this answer is compatible with the Code of Conduct any more.