# Limitation on submitting a question, is it an explicit request to create a new account?

Tags: discussion

When I was trying to ask a new question in Stack Overflow, the following message has been shown:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period

Is it an explicit request to create a new account?

Comment: Related: [70 question limit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/70-question-limit)

Comment: @Arjan, I think they just tweaked the value to 50 instead of 70. Might be same issue.

Comment: It is, @YOU, but a different discussion I guess?

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, it is. I do understand the message, but it's easy to escape by creating a new account, so, why this restriction?

Comment: I guess it's a request for many other things, like answered at [70 question limit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/70-question-limit)

Comment: @jack you might be .. surprised .. at the sorts of additional checks we do on very new users. So yes you can create a new account but you will be subject to some pretty severe rules at that point.

Comment: @Jeff: I'm not challenging your rules, I just would add new question on my same account, that's all. A new account with new 50/30 questions on a new browser will be OK for me.

Comment: If you need to ask 50 questions a month, you are doing something wrong. Whatever you're doing, you're not evolving into a competent programmer.

Comment: @ Pekka's: Actually I do some research before asking any questin, then I write a question then I do more research and check the answers while I do the second research to save time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No it's not an *"explicit request"* to create a new account.

It's a **warning** that your behaviour in asking so many questions is generally undesireable. It's not a flag against you per se but rather everyone asking so many questions.

It means that you probably should be doing some more research before you ask questions.

Don't create a new account as that's not the meaning of the warning.

Answer (score -2):

> Is it an explicit request to create a new account?

I think creating new account will not solve it, since they could [limit at IP level](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72180/clarify-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-error/72205#72205), as long as you hold same IP

Comment: Downvoted sorry, I don't think this answers the question. As its phrased he's trying to figure out what he is **supposed** to do. Not how to bypass some restrictions. I think your answer has merit but isn't applicable.

Comment: Use TOR! Or a proxy. Or a VPN. Or...