# Please notify us somehow before the monthly question quota is reached

Tags: feature-request, notifications

**The request:**

I would suggest warning us before closing the site for some reason.

Something similar to this notification:

> You can only submit 5 question during the following 3 days because you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period.

**The reason:**

I've asked a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89365/limitation-on-submition-question-is-it-an-explicit-request-to-create-a-new-accou) about the problem and *I would say  **Sorry**  for the tone there*.

Actually I was disappointed because I had wanted to ask an urgent question and suddenly I got the `Oops & Sorry` message.

Comment: `I would say Sorry for the accest there.` wat

Comment: @Will don't give a♦: I edited it

Comment: I would make it like the Bounty expiration messages sent to the email.. daily email warning how much questions you can still ask, if you're lower than some threshold. By the way, when using `@` you don't have to use the full name - @Will will work just fine and if you insist on full name, remove the spaces: `@Willdon'tgivea♦` :)

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89670/please-warn-about-exceeding-50-question-limit-prior-to-asking-a-new-question

Comment: Not a duplicate @Wes. This one wants a notification a few questions before the limit, the other one wants the notification after the limit when attempting to ask a new question.