# Show me when I will be able to post again after hitting the maximum number of questions in 30 days

Tags: feature-request, questions, rate-limiting

Once you've been too curious for too long, you hit the Stack Overflow wall:

[image]

Rather than try to post the question every hour until it is finally allowed to go through, it would be nice if SO showed you a message such as, "*You can post another question in 1 day, 18 hours, and 0 minutes*" or some such.

Comment: People asking *that* many questions are almost certainly not spending a lot of time constructing their questions, and tend to be asking fairly low quality questions.  I'm not really bothered by them being bothered a bit.

Comment: But I am bothered a bit by you not being bothered a bit, and I'm even more bothered that I'm still bothered. "Oh, bother," to quote Winnie the Pooh.

Comment: @Servy There's a corner-ish case here - folks with low reputation that hit this restriction thanks for sharing an IP with a bunch of other users.

Comment: Agreed, even if for sake of consistency with other things like accepting an answer. :)

Comment: It's more about that, that doing something like that is about 5 minutes in code (3 minutes to find the place, 1 minute to fix and 1 minute to commit the changes) which would save hundreds of meta questions "when I will be able to ask question again"

Comment: Related request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89670/please-warn-about-exceeding-50-question-limit-prior-to-asking-a-new-question.

Comment: 1207 questions... Good Lord.

Comment: In other news, you will have the pleasure of waiting an hour to post a new question, only to find out at the end of that hour that you need to wait another 59 minutes.