# The question ban does not appear to be relative to IP address in this case

Tags: support, post-ban, multiple-accounts

I was question/post-banned, for some stupid questions when I made my account. I still am and am trying to escape :D Enough of that, though.

My sister, who is using the same Wi-Fi, has the same [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) as me (according to Google). She, however, is currently able to ask just fine. She even tried to login on my computer, and it worked fine. My IP address has been the same for over two years, so it hasn't changed. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Is [the following comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72180/clarify-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-error/76167#comment-174366) old or wrong then?

> "@erick it is permanent by IP, it is lower level than account – Jeff Atwood♦ Dec 14 '10 at 17:34"

Comment: I bet's it's a lot more complicated than we think it is. But the exact workings are of course secrets. Perhaps it takes several question-banned accounts on the same IP before an IP-ban kicks in. That would take care of users abusing the system by creating new accounts and dumping more bad questions.

Comment: I really hope your sister is not upvoting your answers.

Comment: @Mysticial that makes sense, I just assumed it was a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question bans are relative to the account, NOT the IP address (except for serious infractions). Thus, your sister could post questions, while you could not.

Edit: I believe what was meant by *a lower level than the account* was that, if you were to make a new account, it too would be banned from posting questions. May be wrong, would have to ask a mod.

Comment: I can only say 'it depends' .. however if someone did manage to get a new account in the clear, they would soon find it merged with the banned account, with the ban in place and perhaps a timed suspension to boot. We, err .. _strongly advise_ not trying that.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a bug, you were banned for asking several bad questions that had to be closed and were later deleted.

Comment: Yes, I know that, thats not my question...

Comment: I'm just curious (though I plan to never get one), when does/does a question ban expire?

Comment: @MarkRobinson - it has nothing to do with your IP.

Comment: @Telthien Never. [They don't auto-expire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Comment: @NickCraver So Erik's comment is old then?

Comment: @Telthien - in this case, it doesn't.  It's up to the banned user to improve their content rather than posting more questions that are either poor, or a very poor fit.

Comment: @MarkRobinson I'm not sure what the context was, but either it's old, or you're reading it out of context. Or something else

Comment: @NickCraver Good to know, thanks!

Comment: @MarkRobinson - no, it's simply an unrelated case.  You're making a false assumption that there's only one type of ban, level, or reason...none of these are true.

Comment: @Telthien Ok, thank you. Also Nick that's not my question, I know why I am banned. But thank you for the clarification on the IP usage.

Comment: @NickCraver: Could you update the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/141525) to be more accurate in that regard? It says "No. The automatic ban is at a lower level than account." - Perhaps it should then say "No. This will result in a more serious punishment." or something like that? (P.S. It's locked so we can't edit it.)

Comment: @animuson - "it depends" applies here, it is lower level than account but not in this specific case...I won't go into further details on the heuristics.