# Lower level ban should not be imposed due to a single Stack Overflow profile's actions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, ban

I can see the ban on Stack Overflow is on a lower level, such as, if one got banned, his IP address too will be restricted such that no one can post from it again!

I think it will affect many Stack Overflow members since many of the companies use a shared IP address for its employees. We often ask or answer questions here during our worktime. When any member of the company using a Stack Overflow account got banned, then every one else also got restricted from asking or answering questions.

I think it will affect productivity of the entire site and its members interest in contributing here too.

So I suggest to impose a lower level ban when at least `n` profiles got banned from a particular IP address. (`n= 3,4,5...`)

Isn't it?

Comment: How would you deal with an employee of your company that's abusing a common resource and make it difficult for others to use? Or, in other words, why is this Stack Overflow's problem?

Comment: Employees can have various attitudes. Company cant take care how they use internet resources or participates discussions in online sites. Company does not care if stackoverflow bans their IP from asking questions too. Its not a priority for any firm. But I raised this question here to explain how this lower level ban policy is `Unfair` in certain conditions which can affect the site's productivity as well as member's interest in being here as they are banned throughout their office time. If it is not `Stack Overflow's problem`.. I m Out ;)

Comment: I wasn't telling that it's not SO's problem, I was asking (it was an honest question). Anyway, your proposed solution, although smart, it's a bit unfair as well. People who don't share their IP would still get banned normally, but people who share their IP (in a company or otherwise) could pull the same crap and not get banned unless at least `n` of their colleagues were also banned. We'd be essentially penalizing people for not sharing an IP.

Comment: I think the ban is imposed in lower level, for not coming with an another profile with same intentions after being banned here. But some times people without having any particular `intentions` too got banned banning their co workers too! I requested to consider that situations. My suggestion is to ban a profile if he makes noice. But banning his IP should be after n profile's being banned from the same IP... :)

Comment: Off topic: Could you please stop using backticks (`) for emphasis? Backticks are only for code, nothing else.

Comment: If you are having issues with an IP-level ban, you can email the support using the [contact us](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact) link on the main StackExchange website. Explain what's going on, and I'm sure they'll be happy to change the ban type.

Comment: Why are you asking about this? Is this entirely theoretical, or has it happened to you?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a problem Stack Overflow can solve.

IP bans are the last line of defense against serious problem users. They're unfair (as they may affect other, innocent users), but that's the way it is. It is the IP's owner's responsibility to identify the problem user, and deal with them.

It works the same way with spammers, for example. Mail from shared web servers where one user was a spammer will be rejected for all users on that machine, as the machine's IP enters spam blacklists worldwide. It's unfair, but there is nothing you can do about it: the server administrator must remove the spammer, and try to rehabilitate the server IP by talking to each blacklist service.

If you are affected by such a blanket IP ban, you can always contact `team@stackoverflow.com` and ask for help. While I don't know how  likely  they are to lift IP bans on the request of individual users, they're generally pretty reasonable people and may have a way to make things work for you again.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, an IP address ban is the last action moderators can take. You have to misuse several accounts in order to get it.

Comment: I think he means the question rate limit. Maybe

Comment: I think there should be a limit, but it shouldn't be public knowledge.

Comment: I dont think IP ban is a separate action. If i got banned, my IP got banned. look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72180/clarify-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-error/76167#comment-174366

Comment: It is, there was a dicussion on the subject a few days ago.