# Question title out of place under related sidebar

Tags: bug, user-interface, related-questions

The question title should start on the line having the word count. Its not happening [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181792/what-are-the-scopes-of-a-question-ban) :

[image]

The first few words should fit on the first line.

I am guessing its because of the 4 digit vote count.