# Question getting lots of non-answers

Tags: discussion, specific-question, protected-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619801/what-is-the-better-way-to-check-for-an-empty-string-in-delphi) on SO is getting a lot of non-answers posted pretty much continually. As soon as one account is deleted another pops up. Shouldn't an IP ban kick in to prevent the same person creating accounts again and again each time they are deleted? Or auto-protection on the question as there are 6 deleted 1 rep answers.

Comment: Hmm, auto-protection should kick in after three deleted posts by 1 rep users

Comment: Should I add the bug tag to this question then?

Comment: I can't see how many deleted post fitting the criteria are there, so I can't say for certain if it should have kicked in

Comment: I went ahead and manually protected it. I'm not sure why it wasn't auto-protected, but it could be because the old accounts were destroyed, so the auto-protect script couldn't see that they were 1-rep users. (Just speculation on my part.)

Comment: Also, I want some of whatever that guy is smoking.

Comment: @MadScientist: Currently there are 6 spam answers were deleted for that particular question

Comment: BTW, `IP ban` can lead to banning genuine users, as many people may use the same router (with same IP). Maybe, blocking the IP for a while instead of banning might work!

Comment: It might, but that's how question and answer bans work according to [the information I've read on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72180/clarify-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-error/76167#comment-174366).

Comment: @Bill: It's been my experience that the auto-protect only counts live accounts. A question could get a thousand junk answers (that get deleted) but if the user accounts that posted them were deleted/destroyed the auto-protect would never kick in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> protected by Bill the Lizard♦ 2 mins ago
>
> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site.