# Answer bans from post as a guest

Tags: support, answers, help-center, ban

My friend was trying to post an answer as a guest, but he was shown the following message:

> "We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

I don't understand why a guest will get a post ban. And the Help Centre doesn't seem to mention anything about this specific issue. So what can my friend do to resolve the problem?

Comment: Your friend hit a IP address ban, probably. Have him create a proper account.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but after that he create new account and everything is fine.

Comment: Yes, that was what I said they should do.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if it's an IP address ban though, what difference would registering an account make if the user is still accessing the site from the same IP?

Comment: @Cupcake: because such a ban could very well apply differently for guests vs. registered accounts?

Comment: I don't see why unregistered accounts posting bad questions wouldn't incur the same wrath as registered ones.

Answer (score 3):

This is because, as explained in [this faq post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/560258) which says

> No. The automatic ban is at [a lower level than account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72180/clarify-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-error/76167#comment174425_72205). If you do end up creating a new account, it will also receive the same ban.

Which means the most likely outcome was that somebody using the same IP address (possibly a family member, coworker, or schoolmate) got an answer ban, and now the IP address is answer banned.

This should be possible to fix, and here are a couple ways that might fix it

1. take advice from the faq, which says

> The ban also takes into account the IP address. If you browse from a shared computer, or from a location that gives the same IP address to many end users, it's enough that another user who was banned or triggers the ban may affect other users accessing from the same location.

> To help rectify this, browse from a different location.

2. As stated in the comments, creating an account will possibly help.

<sub>I know this was already kinda answered in the comments, but I decided to post it as an actual answer so that it can be helpful to more people in the future, and is more visible.</sub>