# Feature Request: Video to video responses?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, private-messaging

Whenever I go on Stack Overflow I'm always afraid that my questions won't get answered the way I want them to be. I won't get the right answer to one of my questions.

This often demotivates me from even posting a question. I found that I often wasn't able to get across exactly what I wanted to do, and if I did, I often didn't understand the answers that people gave me.

What I'm trying to say is that there's a communication problem between question and answer boards.

What if we had the option for people asking questions to show that they were online and on something like Skype? Then if someone thought they knew the answer, they could try to answer it with Skype? The immediacy of responses would decrease confusion and people could solve problems more effectively, and perhaps even more efficiently. People could even show screen actions in real time with screen recording software instead of a webcam.

Comment: (Just to be sure: [voting works differently here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).)

Comment: Yes, @moguzalp, [apparently there is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66973/why-am-i-getting-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account). (And see also [Should the automated ban on questions used on SO apply to Meta as well?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67023/should-the-automated-ban-on-questions-used-on-so-apply-to-meta-as-well)) Why, and why asking me?

Comment: Ok, @moguzalp, and for anyone getting banned on Meta for having too many downvoted feature requests: I'm sure that can be solved by sending a friendly email to the team then. So: no worries about downvotes *on reasonable posts* here on Meta!

Answer (score 14):

What you describe is an interesting idea, but it's more for a *support* site (possibly as a paid service - I can't see this happening for free, as it's much more demanding of the answerer) than a Q&A site.

There are plenty of ways to ask an intelligible question, and get further clarification in comments. I think the Q&A scheme is working pretty well overall. If you have trouble getting the right answer, maybe look into improving your questions first -  if you have questions about that, you're welcome to ask them here on Meta.

Comment: And, a lot of help on asking has already been written. Like [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and the links in its right-side column.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm always afraid that my questions won't get answered the way I want them to be.

Formulating questions to get the answer you need is a problem in technical writing; this is a chance for you to hone this very important skill. Take advantage of it.

- Think about the words you commit to the input buffer.
- Don't assume that your audience knows the context of the problem--this is often a hard one because you've probably been staring at this problem for a while and have the context fully internalized. Take the time to clearly articulate it.
- Good tagging is your friend. It will help to establish the broad context without a lot of text. Then you can concentrate on explain *your* situation.
- If you have already considered and rejected some avenues ***say so***. And explain why you don't want to go that way.

Comment: I agree with you that my questions do need to be worded better, and that I have to provide feedback for my questions. It's just that it's very time consuming. I also feel that people are already volunteering their time freely and that this method of answering questions doesn't take any more time than the traditional question/answer style. However there seems to be a lot of opposition to the idea. I won't push it, it's merely a suggestion.