# Is there a way for me to get my questions undeleted?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I getting “no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66973/why-am-i-getting-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account)
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

I have lost question asking privileges on stackoverflow due to either too many deleted questions or too many overall downvotes on some deleted questions. I believe that it is the former as I asked a question and promptly removed it a little while before I noticed that I couldn't ask questions. Several of my deleted questions (like the last one) were deleted because I realized that it was trivial shortly after posting it. My questions then are:

- Who would I need to talk to about getting these undeleted for me to edit to standards?

  - I've read that 10k users can undelete them, but am unaware of any way to flag my deleted posts.
  - Should I contact a moderator through the contact us form?

I believe that I can undo this problem by fixing my deleted questions. After looking at my reputation sheet on stackoverflow even with "show removed posts" I have a total of -2 reputation. I also believe that my questions have been on topic, and formatted well. If anyone were to have suggestions on improving them, I'd love to hear them.

Edit: I've managed to find one of my questions and undelete it. The question, while being valid and appropriate for stackoverflow, is somewhat useless. It was trivial and unrelated to the problem at hand. I'm in a position where I can either delete that and remain banned, or leave it on the site until the janitor gets it.

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66973/why-am-i-getting-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account

Comment: I'm not sure why you're directing that link to me. I've read and understand the page I was sent to upon being banned. That's just some angry guy ranting.

Comment: Related: [How do I undelete my question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101361/how-do-i-undelete-my-question), especially [if you still know the id](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101361/how-do-i-undelete-my-question/132859#132859) of the question.

Comment: You say you lost the ability to ask questions. The link I provided, gives all information on this subject.

Answer (score 3):

> Several of my deleted questions (like the last one) were deleted because I realized that it was trivial shortly after posting it.

That's likely why you were question-banned. You're supposed to see if a question is trivial *before posting it*, not after.

More to the point, the proper way to undo a question ban is to contribute answers to the community. If you contribute enough, then your ability to ask questions may be restored. Trying to undelete your questions to do so is not the best way to go about this.

Comment: It wasn't as much that it was trivial, as the problem was a particular case that most likely won't appear in another persons environment. There was a lot of iffy conditional stuff going on with it. The previous employee in my office botched something strange, in a strange place, for a strange reason.

Comment: @NathanMann: Same difference. You are ultimately responsible for making sure that your question is appropriate for SO *before* asking it. If your question can't help anyone else, then it's too localized, and thus not appropriate.

Comment: There was no way for me to know at the time that issue was being caused by those circumstances. That's basically saying not to ask about any code problem that could later turn out be not reproducible due to a system problem or conflict.

Answer (score 2):

I've browsed through your [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431389/nathan-mann?tab=questions):

[image]

and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431389/nathan-mann?tab=answers):

[image]

The worst is what appears to be a [self-promotional question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963284/finding-correct-templates-and-blocks-in-magento), which you answered in the same minute as asking it.

I'm rather surprised you got blocked.  Making some mistakes while you learn to play Stack Overflow is quite natural.   I hope the moderators are willing to have a second look and remove your block.

Comment: I have to say on that, if you take a look the answer your own question link when posting a question it explicitly states that that is allowed.

Comment: It actually in fact states that is encouraged.

Comment: I fail to see how that answer is self-promotional. I don't see any affiliation with the used add-on/plugin? Also, self answering [is a feature nowadays](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz).

Comment: Well, it has 3 downvotes, which is why I listed it as the worst.

Comment: How do you determine that? All I have seen is the -1 @Andomar

Comment: Looks like you need [1000 rep to see up and downvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)